# Postfix Rate limiting according to a particular user

Tags: postfix, email-server, rate-limiting, policyd, postfwd

So this question is again on the table. I have tried to get my answer from forums documents but I wasn't able to find the desired answer.

So, Here is my question I have created a mail server with postfix now what I want is to create quotas for a particular user to send only located number of mail I mentioned. So, for example, if I had 3 users

User1@domain.com 30mails

user2@domain.com 60mails

user3@domain.com 30mails

So these should be the rules and after users send the number of mails they are assigned they should be blocked for a certain time which also I can mention.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with this rule in `postfwd`:

```
id=1; sender=~/random@domain.org/; action=rate(sender/10/300/REJECT rejected for $$sender)
```